# PyQt5 hide folders in QTreeView

Tags: pyqt5

I have something like this :

```
self.model = QFileSystemModel()
self.model.setRootPath(self.dirPath)

self.tree = QTreeView()
self.tree.setModel(self.model)
self.tree.setRootIndex(self.model.index(os.getcwd()))
```

and I wonder how to not display folders at all, only  files.
I did set NameFilters and that worked as a filter for files but it was still showing up a folders. I don't want to see any folders in selected directories.

Comment: If you don't want to show folders, why are you using a tree view (which requires folders to behave as such)?

Comment: That's what I've seen in some tutorial

Comment: That's not the point: a tree view shows hierarchical data models, and since file systems have a hierarchy based on *folders*, if you don't show folders than using a tree view is pointless.

Comment: That's not pointless to me, I want to show images in selected folder but ignore other folders in that folder. Seems reasonable to me

Comment: The fact that you want to show images is completely unrelated to that. You want to show contents of a directory *without* showing the hierarchy of its parent or child elements (so, a tree), then you *don't* need a view that shows hierarchy: a list (QListView) or table (QTableView, if you want to show details) is what you should use instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the name filter won't suffice, as filtering by object type obviously has nothing to do with the object name.

If you just scroll through the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html), you'll see that there's also a [`setFilter()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfilesystemmodel.html#setFilter) function that uses the [QDir.Filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#Filter-enum) flags; the `Files` filter is exactly what you need to only show files.

```
    self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.Files)
```

Since hiding directories obviously makes impossible to show the tree hierarchy, using a QTreeView is pointless.
If you only want to show file names, then you can use a QListView, otherwise QTableView can be used in order to also display file details.